# Group by with a comparing condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by

I have records in a document. Each record has an ID of a person, and a date. I wanna group by records with the same ID, and with date difference of 1 between their date values. For exapmle:

```
ID: 1, Date: 3.13.2023, num: 1
ID: 1, Date: 3.12.2023, num: 2
ID: 1, Date: 2.14.2023, num: 3
```

Will be group by to the first records together, and the last record apart.
How can I do it in MongoDB?

I tried with group by but couldn't think of something to enfore the condition

Comment: could you give more explanation or an example output? because if those data grouped by ID, the result will be only one for each person.

Comment: Of course. I wanna sum the field "num" for each group. But it is the complex group by that holds me back

Comment: did you mean like this [mongo-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WCPNq-QsYLJ)

Comment: No, because i don't want:  {"ID": 1,
    "Date": "2.14.2023",
    "num": 3}. 2.14.2023 should be considered as a different group

Comment: @TobokSitanggang Think of a document with records of "An alert was sent". when an alert is sent right after another alert (or between 24 hours after), then the two "records" represent the same event according to our logic. So i want to group by date, but a simple comparison isn't enough